# ReferenceError: global is not defined in xml2js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xml2js

I want to convert an XML String into JSON so as to fetch some user details. I am using xml2js library.
Below is my typescript code:

**typescript.ts**

```
sendXML(){
    console.log("Inside sendXML method")
    console.log(this.XMLAsString)
    this.parseXML(this.XMLAsString);
}

parseXML(XMLAsString){
    var result;
    var parser=require('xml2js');
    parser.Parser().parseString(XMLAsString, (err, r)=>{result=r});
    console.log(result);
  }
```

**ItrAgainstOrderFilTypeComponent.html**

`<button class="largeButton primaryButton" [disabled]="proceedToVerification" (click)="sendXML()">Proceed to Submit</button>`

The `sendXML()` calls `parseXML()` function which parses the provided String `XMLAsString`.
The `parseXML()` takes the String as a parameter and should print its equivalent JSON.

But when i try to run this code, i get the following error:
`ItrAgainstOrderFilTypeComponent.html:112 ERROR ReferenceError: global is not defined`

This is the first time i am using `xml2js` lib.How do i resolve this? Also, why is it showing an error in the html file (Error is in the html provided above)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to `require` a package inside your browser, it's usally the way to import packages in a Node.js script.

You may need to find another library or use [Browserify](https://browserify.org/).